# Date format with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Any ideas onto why I'm getting a syntax error with this?

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(".$this->news_articles_table."'.date_posted', '%M %D, %Y'");
```

UPDATE:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(".$this->news_articles_table."'.date_posted', '%M %D, %Y')");
```

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM (`news_articles`) JOIN `news_categories` ON
>   `news_articles`.`news_categorie' at line 2
>
> SELECT `news_articles`.`id`, `news_articles`.`article_title`,
>   `news_categories`.`category_name`, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
>   AS author, DATE_FORMAT(news_articles'.date_posted', `'%M` %D, `%Y')`,
>   `statuses`.`status_name` FROM (`news_articles`) JOIN `news_categories`
>   ON `news_articles`.`news_categories_id` =`news_categories`.`id` JOIN
>   `users` ON `news_articles`.`author_id` =`users`.`user_id` JOIN
>   `statuses` ON `news_articles`.`status_id` =`statuses`.`id`
>
> Filename:
>   /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/modules/news/models/news_model.php
>
> Line Number: 74

Comment: Its a syntax error somewhere on that line.

Comment: i'm 100% sure that's not what the error message says.

Comment: you posted one thing "syntax error" turns out to be something else "Database Error" why do you bother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is hidden in the error message. Take a look at your SQL query syntax:

```
DATE_FORMAT(news_articles'.date_posted', `'%M` %D, `%Y')`
```

That doesn't look right, does it?

Because [CI is trying to auto-protect your column names](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select). So, to fix this, you need to pass `FALSE` to the second parameter of `$this->db->select()`, which will stop CI from trying to auto-protect these names.

This should work:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(".$this->news_articles_table.".date_posted, '%M %D, %Y')", FALSE);
```