# what is the use of putting FALSE in select query when using DATE FORMAT in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know reason behind the below code

```
 $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(`current_date`, '%M-%d-%Y' ) as date_human",  FALSE);
```

When i'm using the above code, it is returning a result `July-09-2015`, Now i want to know what is the use of `FALSE` here.Because I'm getting the same result when not adding FALSE.

I have referred the [LINK]([Date format with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074547/date-format-with-code) igniter). In this, the expert says that **it will stop CI from trying to auto-protect these names.**

**Edit:**
When I use `$this->db->last_query`, the query i'm getting is:

```
 SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%M-%d-%Y' ) as date_human FROM `user_data` WHERE id = '57'
```

when using both FALSE and without FALSE.

I want to know the difference and also the use of FALSE.
Guide me to proceed.

Comment: Try to echo your Active Records query with false and without false you'll yourself get your difference

Comment: you mean by putting `$this->db->last_query()`?

Comment: the difference is you're selecting the current date as date_human, so there is no need to add false at your code. In case if you didnt represent the column name means you will get an error, bcaz CI is trying to auto protect your column names, To avoid the issue only we are adding False.  @PHP Learner

Comment: Yes that's what I mean @PHPLearner

Comment: @Uchiha this one is displaying for the both `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`current_date`, '%M-%d-%Y' ) as date_human FROM `user_data` WHERE `id` = '57'`

Comment: Please post it within your question how does it looks @PHPLearner

Comment: The query that you've updated within your question is without false and its having an error over here `user_data``  `<-----` have an extra backtick

Comment: now i have edit it...yes...it is same for both with and without false

Comment: Try to select more than one value @PHPLearner with and without false

Comment: Ya tried it @Uchiha,but same effect

Comment: While the difference is stated within @Abdulla answer you can refer that answer i.e. _CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks._

Comment: I don't understand what is mean by protect your field or table names with backticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$this->db->select()` CodeIgniter auto protect your column names.
If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will **not try to protect** your field or **table names** with `backticks`.

This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Example

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE); 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

[Read CodeIgniter `active_record.html#select`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: what is mean by auto protect?

Comment: You will get answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421873/codeigniter-active-record-get-query-and-query-without-the-limit-clause

Comment: @Nitin i want to know what is menat by `protect your field`? :-( What it refers?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names. This is useful if you need a compound select statement where automatic escaping of fields may break them.

e.g.

```
  $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4) AS amount_paid', FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Refer :
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html