# MySQL select date with a format in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My Codeigniter site select date from a table as follows.

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname, added_date');// working
```

`MYSQL` database has added_dateformat as `2016-09-10 14:44:46` Now i want to select data from table format should be `2016-09-10 14:44 PM`

selecting date separately can get the format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') FROM tble_reg
```

Then how to select other columns with added_date relevant format

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname, DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')'); 
//not working
```

Comment: You need to explain exactly how your query is "not working" — do you get error messages, do you get output in a format you weren't expecting, do you get no output at all? Also if you could tell us the structure of your table, maybe also some example data entries, that'd be helpful.

Comment: If you look at the highlighting, you'll see that when you use the single-quote to specify the date-format, you exit the string for the entire select-query. You can use double-quotes instead `"` or escape them `DATE_FORMAT(added_date, \'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p\')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is speculation, but you might have the single quotes competing with each other.  Does this work?

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname, DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p") as added_date');
```

MySQL allows both single quotes and double quotes for string delimiters, which is handy in cases when single quotes are needed for delimiting strings at the application layer.

Comment: Do I assume from the (anonymous) downvote that this does not work?

Answer (score 4):

Brake the line in to two select statements

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname');
$this->db->select(DATE_FORMAT(added_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AS added_date);
```

Or use  `"` with Date Format

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname, DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p")  AS added_date ');
```

Comment: @Sparten  When brake the lines it makes error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS) `

Comment: `$this->db->select('DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p") AS added_date');` try this

Comment: @Sparten still i'm having error `syntax to use near ':%i %p") AS added_date FROM (`tble_reg`)`

Comment: add your query  here

Comment: @Sparten just added false parameter at the end. now work fine. But dont know why? `$this->db->select('DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p") as added_date', FALSE);`

Answer (score 4):

Answers having little bit errors. following code is working with adding `FLASE` at the end as a parameter. [explanation on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375671/what-is-the-use-of-putting-false-in-select-query-when-using-date-format-in-codei).

```
$this->db->select('reg_id, fname, lname');
$this->db->select('DATE_FORMAT(added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p") as added_date', FALSE);
```